# Seeking information about (category-theoretic) varieties, quasivarieties, and universal Horn classes.

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, universal-algebra

I'm looking for a list of basic facts regarding (category-theoretic) varieties, quasivarieties, and universal Horn categories, as well as information about which forgetful functors preserve what.

In particular, I'd like to know what we **lose** in the passage from variety to quasivariety to universal Horn category.

Comment: Would the passage from a (semi-)lattice (quasi-variety) to a poset (=universal Horn category) count as an example? In this case, the forgetful functor can forget nearly everything, i.e. it is only slightly less forgetful than the functor to the underlying set. (But I fear that's not exactly what you want to know.) If you just look at a variety as a semi-variety (or a universal Horn category), without forgetting anything from the structure, then you won't **lose** anything. So probably I'm not thinking at the intended level of abstraction of your question...